# Spoj minimum bounding rectangle for circle, point and a line. Code caused incomplete score

Tags: c++

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>


void extract_points(int tempx1, int tempy1, int& x1, int& x2, int& y1, int& y2, bool& isFirst){
    if(isFirst){
        x1 = tempx1;
        x2 = tempx1;
        y1 = tempy1;
        y2 = tempy1;
        isFirst = false;
    }else{
        if(tempx1<x1){
            x1=tempx1;
        }else if(tempx1>x2){
            x2=tempx1;
        }
        if(tempy1<y1){
            y1=tempy1;
        }else if(tempy1>y2){
            y2=tempy1;
        } 
    }
}

void extract_circles(int tempx1, int tempy1, int radius, int& x1, int& x2, int& y1, int& y2, bool& isFirst){
    if(isFirst){
        x1 = tempx1-radius;
        x2 = tempx1+radius;
        y1 = tempy1-radius;
        y2 = tempy1+radius;
        isFirst = false;
    }else{
        if(tempx1-radius<x1){
            x1=tempx1-radius;
        }
        if(tempx1+radius>x2){
            x2=tempx1+radius;
        }
        if(tempy1-radius<y1){
            y1=tempy1-radius;
        }
        if(tempy1+radius>y2){
            y2=tempy1+radius;
        }
    }
}

void extract_lines(int tempx1, int tempy1, int tempx2, int tempy2, int& x1, int& x2, int& y1, int& y2, bool& isFirst){
    if(isFirst){
        if(tempx1>tempx2){
            x1 = tempx2;
            x2 = tempx1;
            isFirst = false;
        }else if(tempx1<tempx2){
            x1 = tempx1;
            x2 = tempx2;
            isFirst = false;
        }
        if(tempy1>tempy2){
            y1 = tempy2;
            y2 = tempy1;
            isFirst = false;
        }else if(tempy1<tempy2){
            y1 = tempy1;
            y2 = tempy2;
            isFirst = false;
        } 
    }else{
        if(tempx1<x1){
            x1=tempx1;
        }else if(tempx1>x2){
            x2=tempx1;
        }
        if(tempy1<y1){
            y1=tempy1;
        }else if(tempy1>y2){
            y2=tempy1;
        }
        if(tempx2<x1){
            x1=tempx2;
        }else if(tempx2>x2){
            x2=tempx2;
        }
        if(tempy2<y1){
            y1=tempy2;
        }else if(tempy2>y2){
            y2=tempy2;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int testcase, amount_of_obj;
    int tempx1, tempx2, tempy1, tempy2, radius;
    char character;
    std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int, int>> output_coordinates;
    scanf(" %d", &testcase);
    while(testcase>0){
        int x1 = 0, x2 = 0, y1 = 0, y2 = 0;
        bool isFirst = true;
        scanf(" %d", &amount_of_obj);
        while(amount_of_obj>0){
            scanf(" %c", &character);
            if(character == 'p'){
                scanf(" %d %d", &tempx1, &tempy1);
                extract_points(tempx1, tempy1, x1, x2 ,y1, y2, isFirst);
            }else if(character == 'c'){
                scanf(" %d %d %d", &tempx1, &tempy1, &radius);
                extract_circles(tempx1, tempy1, radius, x1, x2 ,y1, y2, isFirst);
            }else if(character == 'l'){
                scanf(" %d %d %d %d", &tempx1, &tempy1, &tempx2, &tempy2);
                extract_lines(tempx1, tempy1, tempx2, tempy2, x1, x2 ,y1, y2, isFirst);
            }
            amount_of_obj--;
        }output_coordinates.push_back(std::make_tuple(x1, y1, x2, y2));
        testcase--;
    }
    for(const std::tuple<int, int, int, int>& funni_tuples : output_coordinates){
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d %d %d %d", std::get<0>(funni_tuples), std::get<1>(funni_tuples), std::get<2>(funni_tuples), std::get<3>(funni_tuples));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the spoj link is this: https://www.spoj.com/problems/HS12MBR/

I have had error and had asked bing to fact check or generated inputs and output, it has proofed that my functions were the main problem, though after a lot of time spent I still could not get the full 100points.

I got a score of 80 point but I should be getting 100pt if I have a full proof code, anyone with a kind heart know? Thanks!

Comment: Oh.. yet another competitive coding site... great. Those sites are usually not good at teaching C++. In your case I am pretty certain you don't have a C++ problem but an algorithm one.

Comment: Given the language tag, consider implementing a MBR class, with a method `add_point` which expands (or not) the bounding rectangle. Also, I'd avoid `scanf` even in C, you could start learnig about `iosream`.

Comment: Pepijn Kramer is there anything I could try and learn other than these competitive coding sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll point out only one issue in the posted code

```
void extract_lines( int tempx1, int tempy1, int tempx2, int tempy2
                  , int& x1, int& x2, int& y1, int& y2
                  , bool& isFirst ) {
    if(isFirst) {
        if(tempx1>tempx2) {
            x1 = tempx2;
            x2 = tempx1;
            isFirst = false;
        }else if(tempx1<tempx2){    // <----
            x1 = tempx1;
            x2 = tempx2;
            isFirst = false;
        }

        // [...] The same pattern is present in all the following checks
    }
    // [...]
}
```

The problem is that `tempx1` may be *equal* to `tempx2` and in that case the function doesn't update any of the variables passed by reference.

The `else if` should be a simple `else`, here, to take into account all the cases. As an alternative, the OP may try to use [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) and [`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min).